# System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException in constructor

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I am keep getting

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException

and PresentationFramework.dll, additional info Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.

Can someone please help me out here?

Info:
Call Stack

> PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Markup.WpfXamlLoader.Load(System.Xaml.XamlReader xamlReader, System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory writerFactory, bool skipJournaledProperties, object rootObject, System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings settings, System.Uri baseUri)   Unknown

```
    namespace PMD.Analysis.AnalysisViewModel
        {
            using PMD.Measurement.MeasurementModel;
            using System.Windows.Data;
            using PMD.Analysis.AnalysisModel;
            using System;
            using System.Collections.Generic;
            using PMD.Measurement.MeasurementViewModel;
            public class AnalysisViewModel : ViewModel
            {

        /// <summary>
        /// New analysis command.
        /// </summary>
        private ICommand newAnalysis = null;
        public PMD.Analysis.AnalysisViewModel.NewAnalysisViewModel m_NewAnalysisViewModel;
        Measurement measurement = new Measurement();
        private ICollectionView measurements = null;
        /// <summary>
        /// Measurement's search by title field.
        /// </summary>
        private string searchTitle;
        /// <summary>
        /// Measurement's search by title field.
        /// </summary>
        private string searchTester;
        /// <summary>
        /// Measurement's search by vehicle VIN field.
        /// </summary>
        private string searchVehicleVIN;

        public MeasurementModel MeasurementModel
        {
            get;
            set;
        }


        public enum SelectedState
        {
            // No Masurements.
            Inactive,
            // Masurements.
            Active,
            // Waiting for Masurements.
            WaitingAnswer
        };


        public SelectedState CurrentSelectedState { get; set; }

        public Analysis Analysis
        {
            get;
            set;
        }

        public AnalysisViewModel()
        {

            Analysis = new Analysis();
            measurements = new ListCollectionView(MeasurementModel.Measurements);
            measurements.Filter = new Predicate<object>(SearchCallbackAnalysis);
        }

        ~AnalysisViewModel()
        {

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// List of measurements that will be displayed in analysis view.
        /// </summary>
        public ICollectionView Measurements
        {
            get { return measurements; }

            set { measurements = value; }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets new analysis command.
        /// </summary>
        public ICommand NewAnalysis
        {
            get
            {
                if (newAnalysis == null)
                    newAnalysis = new NewAnalysisCommand(this);
                return newAnalysis;
            }
        }


        public bool SearchCallbackAnalysis(object item)
        {
            bool isItemShowed = true;
            if ((searchTitle != "") && (searchTitle != null))
                isItemShowed &= (((Measurement)item).Title == searchTitle);
            if ((searchVehicleVIN != "") && (searchVehicleVIN != null))
                isItemShowed &= (((Measurement)item).Vehicle.VehicleVIN == searchVehicleVIN);
            if ((SearchTester != "") && (SearchTester != null))
                isItemShowed &= (((Measurement)item).Tester == SearchTester);
            return isItemShowed;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets measurement's search by title field.
        /// </summary>
        public string SearchTitle
        {
            get
            {
                return searchTitle;
            }

            set
            {

                searchTitle = value;
                Measurements.Refresh();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets measurement's search by tester name field.
        /// </summary>
        public string SearchTester
        {
            get
            {
                return searchTester;
            }

            set
            {

                searchTester = value;
                Measurements.Refresh();
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets measurement's search by vehicle VIN field.
        /// </summary>
        public string SearchVehicleVIN
        {
            get
            {
                return searchVehicleVIN;
            }
            set
            {    
                searchVehicleVIN = value;
                Measurements.Refresh();
            }
        }      
    }//end AnalysisViewModel

}//end namespace AnalysisViewModel
```

if i comment in constructor this line of code:

```
measurements.Filter = new Predicate<object>(SearchCallbackAnalysis);
```

Everything works fine but i need this line to search in the list.

Additional info:

```
xamlReader  Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'xamlReader' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.  System.Xaml.XamlReader

writerFactory   Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'writerFactory' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.   System.Xaml.IXamlObjectWriterFactory

skipJournaledProperties Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'skipJournaledProperties' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away. bool

rootObject  Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'rootObject' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.  object

settings    Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'settings' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away.    System.Xaml.XamlObjectWriterSettings

baseUri Cannot obtain value of local or argument 'baseUri' as it is not available at this instruction pointer, possibly because it has been optimized away. System.Uri
```

Comment: I think we need more information, can you add the complete exception stack and the complete exception message and inner message? I dont think that the problem is at the constructor with the Predicate. Can you add a break point at the SearchCallbackAnalysis is it called?

Comment: an have add a break point to  SearchCallbackAnalysis an i get the exception before the SearchCallbackAbalysis is called. but i use this method in other class and works. i put the break point at  measurements = new ListCollectionView(MeasurementModel.Measurements); and the exception i still have it

Comment: the source information for this exception is not available or is missing from debug information for this module

Answer (score 0):

i have try:

```
public ICollectionView Measurements
        {
            get { return measurements; }

            set { measurements = value; 
measurements.Filter = new Predicate<object>(SearchCallbackAnalysis);
}
        }
```

Now everything works fine. Thank you for try to help me.